# I've been trying to use dc.js and crossfilter to build the datatable functionality to listout some data.But the data is not displaying as expected

Tags: d3.js, dc.js, crossfilter

I've been trying to use dc.js and crossfilter to build the datatable functionality to listout some data.But the data is not displaying as expected

My data sample

```
{
   "name": "Thomas Ludlow Hallaway",
   "urlslug": "\\/wiki\\/thomas_ludlow_hallaway_(new_earth)",
   "id": "secret identity",
   "align": "bad characters",
   "eye": "brown eyes",
   "hair": "brown hair",
   "sex": "male characters",
   "gsm": "",
   "alive": "deceased characters",
   "appearances": 36,
   "first appearance": "1940, may",
   "year": 1940
 },
 {
   "name": "Jeannette",
   "urlslug": "\\/wiki\\/jeannette_(new_earth)",
   "id": "secret identity",
   "align": "bad characters",
   "eye": "blue eyes",
   "hair": "white hair",
   "sex": "female characters",
   "gsm": "",
   "alive": "living characters",
   "appearances": 35,
   "first appearance": "2009, january",
   "year": 2009
 }
```

My code

```
function listCharacters(ndx) {
  var dim = ndx.dimension(dc.pluck("name"));
  dc.dataTable("#all-characters")
      .dimension(dim)
      .group(function(d) {
        return "";
      })
      .columns(["name", "urlslug", "first appearance"])
      .size(Infinity)
      .sortBy("name")

      .order(d3.ascending)
      .transitionDuration(1000);
}
```

Expected Output

> Name        urlslug                                      first appearance
>   Thomas     \/wiki\/jeannette_(new_earth)              1940, may 
>   Jeannette    \/wiki\/thomas_ludlow_hallaway_(new_earth) 2009, january

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Running your code produces the following error in the developer tools console. (A super helpful tool for all coding in D3 and dc.js!)

```
Uncaught TypeError: _sortBy is not a function
    at VM164 dc.js:7999
    at Array.sort (<anonymous>)
    at nestEntries (VM164 dc.js:7998)
    at renderSections (VM164 dc.js:7962)
    at Object._chart._doRender (VM164 dc.js:7874)
    at Object._chart.render (VM164 dc.js:2092)
    at Object.dc.renderAll (VM164 dc.js:251)
    at (index):85
    at dispatch (VM161 jquery-1.11.0.js:4624)
    at elemData.handle (VM161 jquery-1.11.0.js:4292)
```

The issue is that `.sortBy()` takes a function - [here are the docs](https://dc-js.github.io/dc.js/docs/html/dc.dataTable.html#sortBy__anchor).

Fixing that, we get basic, decent output, below. It still needs a lot of formatting using CSS, or you might consider using [dc-tableview](https://github.com/karenpommeroy/dc-tableview) or [dc.datatables.js](https://github.com/dc-js/dc.datatables.js) if you want features like pagination.

[image: screenshot of output table]

[Here's a fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/gordonwoodhull/17tfe5p0/12/) with the working code.